# Send a Google Chat message in Python

Tags: python, rest, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to send a Google Chat message from Python in much the same way you can send a Gmail message:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

I see documentation on how to create a Chat Bot (https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/bots-develop), but these typically require that you create your own https server that google can access.

I've tried using the scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat', and it successfully goes through the authorization flow, and in particular the 'chat' scope claims to grant permissions to send messages, etc:

(see https://vizycam.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Image-634-1.jpg)

I can build a request using build() and the granted credentials:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
...
service = build('chat', 'v1', credentials=gcloud.creds())
```

and I can see that it has methods dms(), rooms(), spaces(), etc. that I could use to create a message, but I'm unable to get any requests to work.

Is it possible to send a chat message from a user account programmatically, in much the same way the Gmail example above does?

Comment: Would it be an option to use a webhook from Google chat that you can make requests from your Python code to send the messages? The message would be sent by the webhook "bot" rather than a user account

Comment: The problem with webhooks is that you need to stand up your own server, and this server cannot be behind a firewall.  You can easily send a Gmail message from a user account without needing to set up a server, etc., but sending a Chat message requires much more complexity -- it seems odd... 

Is it possible to send a Chat message from a user account in the same way the Gmail example does (using scopes, credentials and requests)?

Comment: You don't have to stand up your own server for webhooks. Take a look at this doc: https://developers.google.com/chat/quickstart/incoming-bot-python

Comment: My primary point is that you can't do it easily from a user account.  Webhooks require a Google Workspace account (https://support.google.com/chat/answer/9291345?hl=en)